# How to create a GWT project with MAVEN support?

Tags: java, maven, gwt, configuration

I have core experience of `maven`(on console) and `GWT`. Now I want to create a simple `GWT Project` with the support of `maven` in eclipse. Is there is any tutorial for `GWT-Maven` ?
so please describe step by step procedure to configuration in eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

[gwt-maven-plugin](https://gwt-maven-plugin.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/) is useful.

Created project by following command can be imported as "Existing Maven Projects" on Eclipse.

```
$ mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo -DarchetypeArtifactId=gwt-maven-plugin -DarchetypeVersion=2.7.0
```

Comment: hey I am running this command on windows console but its prompting me for not a internal or external command.

Comment: yeah!! I have got the command for windows but its giving me error " no pom in the directory".

Comment: As @yukihane worte. Execute that command on an existing maven project. Which means, that there is already an existing `pom.xml`. Read [maven in 5 minutes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) in order to create a project from scratch. Execute the command from @yukihane afterwards.